# How can I multiply to each array of object values with a constant?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I multiple each element of array of object value with a constant?

**Input**

```
[{"key":usd, "value":20 }, {"key":aed, "value":50 },{"inr":usd, "value":30 },{"key":usd, "value":40 }]
```

**Output**

```
[{"key":usd, "value":40 }, {"key":aed, "value":100 },{"inr":usd, "value":60 },{"key":usd, "value":80 }]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried and we'll be happy to give you a hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const arr = [{"key":"usd", "value":20 }, {"key":"aed", "value":50 },{"inr":"usd", "value":30 },{"key":"usd", "value":40 }];

const modifiedArr = arr.map(item => {
    var modifiedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
    modifiedItem.value *= 2;

    return modifiedItem;
});

console.log(arr);
console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Edit: used modifiedItem for immutability as pointed out by @UncleDave

Comment: This mutates the original array, that may or may not be desirable behaviour however calling the result `modifiedArr` is misleading as the contents of `arr`have also been modified.

Comment: I've edited the function - used a new object in map for immutability purpose... +1

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [{"key":"usd", "value":20 }, {"key":"aed", "value":50 },{"inr":"usd", "value":30 },{"key":"usd", "value":40 }];
arr.map(function(value,key){
    arr[key].value *=2;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Output

```
[{"key":"usd", "value":40 }, {"key":"aed", "value":100 },{"inr":"usd", "value":60 },{"key":"usd", "value":80 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

without mutating your original array. feel free to comment if you don't understand.

```js
let someArray = [{"key":"usd", "value":20 }, {"key":"aed", "value":50 },{"inr":"usd", "value":30 },{"key":"usd", "value":40 }]

let result = someArray.map(data=>{
return {...data, value: data.value*2}
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sample function for this input type,in other case you have to change this function,pass your object as input:

```
valueChanger(input){
    var tx = []
    for(var x = 0;x < Object.keys(input).length ; x++){
        var obj = {}
        obj['key'] = input[x]['key'] // do anything with key if you want in here
        obj['value'] = input[x]['value']*2 
        tx.push(obj)
    }
    return tx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [ES6 arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```js
const arr = [{
  "key": "usd",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "key": "aed",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "inr": "usd",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "key": "usd",
  "value": 40
}];
const value = 2;
const result = arr.map(e => {
  e.value *= value;
  return e;
});
console.log(result);
```

And if you want to, you can just return the doubled values like this, by returning the doubles value of `e.value`:

```js
const arr = [{
  "key": "usd",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "key": "aed",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "inr": "usd",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "key": "usd",
  "value": 40
}];
const value = 2;
const result = arr.map(e => e.value *= value);
console.log(result);
```